# How to drop and recreate table in destination server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

Here is the scenario for which Iam trying to create a SSIS package using VS2013. We have SQLServer2014 servers - A & B.

From ServerA.Database1, need to copy data for few specific tables to ServerB.Database2.

But before copy, have to drop the table and recreate the table at destination (ServerB.Database2) using the table schema from source (ServerA.Database1) because of schema changes happening frequently. Need to schedule this weekly.

How to accomplish using SSIS (how to retrieve source table schema information in the ssis package so that it will be used to create a table at the destination) ? or any other way ?

Thanks

Bhanu.

Comment: you can use "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task"

Answer (score 1):

Add an execute sql task and provide sql text 'Drop table tablename' and then create table tablename (variables and datatypes)

Comment: How to retrieve the table schema from source so that can be created at destination ?

Comment: you need to get that from source team

Comment: Question is about how to retrieve the schema information from source table within the ssis package.

Answer (score 0):

Below approach will require a Linked Server. No need to worry about table schema.

```
Drop table TargetServer.database.dbo.tablename
Insert * into TargetServer.database.dbo.tablename from SourceServer.database.dbo.tablename
```